# Getting all nodes at a level in full binary tree, array format

Tags: php, arrays, binary-tree

I need to get all the nodes at a certain level in a full binary tree from either the left or right subtree. I currently retrieve the binary tree from the DB as an array, for example:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` represents a tree like this:

```
                                     1
                                    / \
                                   /   \
                                  2     3
                                 / \   / \
                                /   \ /   \
                               4    5 6    7
```

So what I need to do is basically grab a level of the tree and return it as an array. Something like `level(3,"left") -> [4,5]` or `level(2, "right") -> [3]`. I was thinking about creating a BinaryTree object doing it recursively, but I can't think of a way to keep track of the level within the call without having to tag every node with a level or something like that as I'd like to keep the DB as clean as possible. Any ideas?

Edit: I really need all the nodes at a level for the left or right subtree, not the whole tree. I'm displaying a tournament, so I need to split it half and half. If I didn't have to split it, I could probably do this:

```
function level($array, $level_num) {
    return array_slice($array, pow(2, $level_num)-1, pow(2, $level_num));
}
```

I don't really know how to extend this for getting only the left or right subtree's level array.

Comment: That's a really cool problem. Give it a try and show your failing code.  Also note that the image you rendered doesn't match the example array. The array has a 4 and no 8. The image has no 4 but has an 8.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Sorry, didn't notice that. Just updated it.

Comment: Ok I wrote a solution. in your OP, the `level(3)` still contains `8` even though it's not in the tree.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah, my bad, its another typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted BeetleJuice's answer for using the "Shift Left" bitwise operator `<<` -- it is the perfect building block for this task.

This is as clean as I can make my coding attempt:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6cc07d3ea4771b9b6bf9855e4d3ef868732a9bb2))

```
function getForkinValues($array,$level,$side='left'){ // left side fork is default
    if($level==1) return current($array);
    $length=$level>2?1<<($level-2):1;  // number of elements to return
    $index=(1<<$level-1)-1;            // first index to return
    if($side=='right') $index+=$length;  // shift to correct index for 'right'
    if(!isset($array[$index+$length-1])) return 'Error: Insufficient Array Length';
    return array_slice($array,$index,$length);

}
$array=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'];
var_export(getForkinValues($array,3,'right'));
```

Comment: @ashraj98 I'm not referencing any indices.  This function (like BeetleJuice's) doesn't bother "growing the full tree".  It determines the integers in the nominated "level" of the tree and returns an array of values in the nominated fork.  Building a full tree (multi-dim array) only to extract a small portion of it -- is inefficient / wasteful.  Best practice is to only build what you need.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after looking over it for a bit. Suppose the tree nodes were not `[1,2,3,4,5,...]`? I only used the tree in the OP as an example. In the actual usage, the node values are IDs of models in Laravel, so it's not ever going to be like the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Adjust depth as needed
$depth = 3;

// using bit arithmetic. '<< 3' means multiply by 2 three times.
$start = 1 << $depth-1; // 1 * (2 * 2) because depth is 3
$end = (1 << $depth) -1; // 1 * (2 * 2 * 2) - 1

// if depth=3, this is [4,5,6,7]
$fullLevel = range($start, $end);

print_r($fullLevel);

if($depth > 1):
    $leftBranch = array_slice($fullLevel,0,count($fullLevel)/2);
    $rightBranch = array_slice($fullLevel,count($fullLevel) / 2);

    print_r($leftBranch); // [4,5]
    print_r($rightBranch); // [6, 7]
endif;
```

Comment: I realized as well that getting the left or right part is simply splitting it in half. Any advantage to using `<<` rather than `pow()`, or is there some difference I'm missing?

Comment: @ashraj98 `pow()` will get away from you... Here is a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2dd1aea11831b11e9033d5174091d25407a996ce).