# print a tree in a table format from an array

Tags: php, arrays, binary-tree

Hi I am trying to print an array which has node value and depth parameters as a tree in table format like below.

My Current code which will print as a tree view format below:

```
if(count($nodes) > 0){
    $depth = -1;
    $flag = false;
    foreach ($nodes as $row) {
        while ($row->depth > $depth) {
            echo "<ul><li><a href='javascript:void(0);'>";
            $flag = false;
            $depth++;
        }
        while ($row->depth < $depth) {
            echo "</a></li></ul>";
            $depth--;
        }
        if ($flag) {
            echo "</a></li><li><a href='javascript:void(0);'>";
            $flag = false;
        }
        echo $row->name.'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger margin-left-20 removeBtn" data-name="'.$row->name.'">Delete</button>' ;
        $flag = true;
    }
    while ($depth-- > -1) {
        echo "</a></li></ul>";
    }
}else{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Warning!</strong> There were no nodes in the tree!</div>';
}
```

Example Array:

```
Value  Depth

12       0

13       1

14       1

25       2

20       2

21       2

16       2

23       3

24       3
```

I am able to print in a normal tree view but when i am trying to print as a table format i can't able to do it somehow.

Expected Format:

Table first row 12[0] entire row

Table second row will be shared by 13[1] and 14[1]

Table third row will be shared by 25[2], 20[2] and 21[]2

Table fourth row will be shared by 16[3], 23[3] and 24[3]

So logic is each row of the table will be shared equally by the same depth node values.

Comment: SO is not `write me code for my requirements` service, which you should already know by now. Show your current code

Comment: my current code prints as a tree view but i am not even getting a idea at all, anyway i will add my current code.

Comment: I recommend you read **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**, next **[how to create Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** - then edit your question accordingly to potentially attract more attention.

Comment: added my current code

Comment: how do you get the value? why you are increment/decrements depth?

Comment: Entire array will be called as $nodes and you can access the node value as $node->value and depth as $node->depth

Comment: I didn't get it about increment/decrement depth

Comment: If your array data is always output in a "forking" pattern on each level, you don't need to assign `0`, `1`, `2`, etc for the levels.  Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45291652/2943403

Comment: Here is a quick demo of what I can work from if you want a more refined method: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e41fa6daefe94eff984b032914619959d951dda9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create unique array by `depth` as key.

```
$temp_nodes = [];

if (count($nodes) > 0) {
    foreach ($nodes as $key => $row) {
        $temp_nodes[$row->depth][] = $row;
    }
}
```

The above code will make array with unique depth as key & all same depth record under that array. Then iterate the array & display:

```
foreach ($temp_nodes as $key => $temp_node) {
    foreach ($temp_node as $node) {
       echo "$node->value [$key]";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
12 [0]
13 [1]14 [1]
25 [2]20 [2]21 [2]16 [2]
23 [3]24 [3]
```