# Make an output of 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18... using one for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, increment

How can I generate a sequence of numbers like

> 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18 ...

(plus 10 every 4 numbers) with the following additional requirements:

- using only *one* loop
- output should stop when a value in the sequence is greater than a specified input

#### Examples

```
$input = 24;
```

> 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18 21 22 24

```
$input = 20;
```

> 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18

Here's what I tried so far:

```
<?php 

// sample user input 
$input = 20; 

$number = 1; 
$counter = 0; 
$array = array(); 

//conditions 
while ($counter < 4) { 
    $counter++;
    array_push($array, $number); 
    $number += $number;
} 

//outputs 
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
    echo $array[$x];
    echo " ";
}
```

Comment: So where's your code that you need help with?

Comment: What I have with me is this:

<?php
// sample user input
$input = 20;
$number = 1;
$counter = 0;
$array = array();
//conditions

    while ($counter < 4) {
        $counter++;
        array_push($array, $number);
        $number += $number;
    }

//outputs
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
    echo $array[$x];
    echo " ";
}
?>

the output of this should be: 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18 because the user input is 20

Comment: This is a good question and it has been edited to reflect what I believe the original poster is asking. Please consider reopening.

Comment: @localheinz I think you are perhaps interpreting the OP's request for "one for loop" too literally.  The OP's coding attempt (which was commented 9 minutes after posting) was using two separate loops, and I think that there is a fair chance that she just wanted to reduce the method to a single loop.  It is probably unimportant to the OP to restrict the type of loop that is implemented.  If you downvoted any of the other answers because of this literal interpretation, I would like to politely ask you to un-downvote  any answers where this was the only issue.

Comment: @mickmackusa Maybe the original poster would like to clarify what she wanted?

Answer (score 0):

**Code:** ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c03ff2bfdccfa2a8e129931253ab344b13c9661))

```
function arrayBuilder($max,$num=1){
    $array=[];
    for($i=0; ($val=($num<<$i%4)+10*floor($i/4))<=$max; ++$i){
        $array[]=$val;
    }
    return $array;
}
echo implode(',',arrayBuilder(28)),"\n"; // 1,2,4,8,11,12,14,18,21,22,24,28
echo implode(',',arrayBuilder(28,2)),"\n"; // 2,4,8,16,12,14,18,26,22,24,28
echo implode(',',arrayBuilder(20)),"\n"; // 1,2,4,8,11,12,14,18
echo implode(',',arrayBuilder(24)),"\n"; // 1,2,4,8,11,12,14,18,21,22,24
```

This method is very similar to localheinz's answer, but uses a technique introduced to me by [beetlejuice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45291818/2943403) which is faster and php version safe.  I only read localheinz's answer just before posting; this is a matter of nearly identical intellectual convergence.  I am merely satisfying the brief with the best methods that I can think of.

**How/Why does this work without a lookup array or if statements?**

- When you call `arrayBuilder()`, you must send a `$max` value (representing the highest possible value in the returned array) and optionally, you can nominate `$num` (the first number in the returned array) otherwise the default value is `1`.
- Inside `arrayBuilder()`, `$array` is declared as an empty array.  This is important if the user's input value(s) do not permit a single iteration in the `for` loop.  This line of code is essential for good coding practices to ensure that under no circumstances should a Notice/Warning/Error occur.
- A `for` loop is the most complex loop in php (so says [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)), and its three expressions are the perfect way to package the techniques that I use.

  - The first expression `$i=0;` is something that php developers see all of the time.  It is a one-time declaration of `$i` equalling `0` which only occurs `before` the first iteration.
  - The second expression is the only *tricky/magical* aspect of my entire code block.  This expression is called `before` every iteration.  I'll try to break it down: (parentheses are vital to this expression to avoid unintended results due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

    - `(` open parenthesis to contain leftside of comparison operator
    - `$val=` declare `$val` for use inside loop on each iteration
    - `($num<<$i%4)` because of precedence this is the same as `$num<<($i%4)` meaning: "find the remainder of `$i` divided by 4 then use the [bitwise "shift left" operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to "multiply `$num` by `2` for every "remainder". This is a very fast way of achieving the 4-number pattern of `[don't double],[double once],[double twice],[double three times]` to create:  `1,2,4,8`, `2,4,8,16`, and so on. `bitwise operators` are always more efficient than `arithmetic operators`.
      The use of the [arithmetic operator modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) ensure that the intended core number pattern repeats every four iterations.
    - `+` add (not concatenation in case there is any confusion)
    - `10*floor($i/4)` round down `$i` divided by `4` then multiply by `10` so that the first four iterations get a bonus of `0`, the next four get `10`, the next four get `20`, and so on.
    - `)` closing parenthesis to contain leftside of comparison operator
    - `<=$max` allow iteration until the `$max` value is exceeded.
  - `++$i` is [pre-incrementing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) `$i` at the `end` of every iteration.

Answer (score -1):

Complex solution using `while` loop:

```
$input = 33;
$result = [1];  // result array
$k = 0;         // coeficient
$n = 1;

while ($n < $input) {
    $size = count($result);   // current array size
    if ($size < 4) {          // filling 1st 4 values (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8)
        $n += $n;
        $result[] = $n;
    }
    if ($size % 4 == 0) {     // determining each 4-values sequence
        $multiplier = 10 * ++$k;
    }
    if ($size >= 4) {
        $n = $multiplier + $result[$size - (4 * $k)];
        if ($n >= $input) {
            break;
        }
        $result[] = $n;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 14
    [7] => 18
    [8] => 21
    [9] => 22
    [10] => 24
    [11] => 28
    [12] => 31
    [13] => 32
)
```

Comment: Not using a `for` loop.

Comment: @localheinz, it would not make a difference, if you know how loops work. The main thing here is the algorithm. But, it seems that the OP doesn't care about algorithms at all

Comment: Original poster asked for a single `for` loop, your answer is not using a `for` loop.

Comment: @localheinz, now I see that you also doesn't care much about algorithms (and loops also). `while` and `for` will do the same in this case. it's just the game of words

Comment: Maybe you should take more time to read the question before answering.

Comment: I'm not struggling, are you?

Comment: @localheinz, I just tried to deliver my clear position. I haven't been starting to leave a comments under other answers

Answer (score -2):

On closer inspection, each value in the sequence of values you desire can be calculated by adding the corresponding values of two sequences.

#### Sequence A

```
 0  0  0  0 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20
```

#### Sequence B

```
 1  2  4  8  1  2  4  8  1  2  4  8
```

#### Total

```
 1  2  4  8 11 12 14 18 21 22 24 28
```

### Solution

#### Prerequisite

The index of the sequences start with `0`. Alternatively, they could start with `1`, but then we would have to deduct `1`, so to keep things simple, we start with `0`.

#### Sequence A

```
$a = 10 * floor($n  / 4);
```

The function `floor()` accepts a numeric value, and will cut off the fraction.

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions.

#### Sequence B

```
$b = 2 ** ($n  % 4);
```

The operator `**` combines a *base* with the *exponent* and calculates the result of raising *base* to the power of *exponent*.

In PHP versions prior to PHP 5.6 you will have to resort to using `pow()`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php.

The operator `%` combines two values and calculates the remainder of dividing the former by the latter.

#### Total

```
$value = $a + $b;
```

#### Putting it together

```
$input = 20;

// sequence a
$a = function ($n) {
    return 10 * floor($n  / 4);
};

// sequence b
$b = function ($n) {
    return 2 ** ($n  % 4);
};

// collect values in an array
$values = [];

// use a for loop, stop looping when value is greater than input
for ($n = 0; $input >= $value = $a($n) + $b($n) ; ++$n) {
    $values[] = $value;
}

echo implode(' ', $values);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/pp9Ci