# Number sequence of 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18 using only one variable and one for loop

Tags: loops, variables, for-loop, numbers

I am asked to provide an algorithm using only one variable and one for loop only. Without using functions, array or any other functions. Just one input which is the only variable, and one single for loop, and it should display a number sequence of 1 2 4 8 ... depending on the input value. You will input the value in a form then after submitting, that posted data will be the only variable to be manipulated.

e.g. the input value is 20 so it should display

> 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18

if the input value is 50, it should display

> 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18 21 22 24 28 31 32 34 38 41 42 44 48

I know there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025060/make-an-output-of-1-2-4-8-11-12-14-18-using-one-for-loop) like this that has already been asked but I think it's already closed.

This is the hardest problem so far I've encountered in php mathematical problems. Please help me.

Somebody who got this working gave me a clue and it's only a matter of equation in the **3rd element** of **For Loop** which is traditionally designed for incrementing/decrementing

A working example of this is like this. (Thanks to [localheinz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172545/localheinz))

```
<?php 
$input = 20;
        $a = function ($n) {
            return 10 * floor($n  / 4);
        };
        $b = function ($n) {
            return 2 ** ($n  % 4);
        };
        for ($n = 0; $input >= $value = $a($n) + $b($n) ; ++$n){
            echo $value." ";      
        }
?>
```

But you all know it's not in one single variable and it's using functions. So that will not be accepted even though it shows the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$input` is not counted as a variable then this may be a solution

```
<?php
$input = 20;
for ($i = 0; (2 ** ($i % 4) + 10 * floor($i / 4)) <= $input; $i++) {
    echo (2 ** ($i % 4) + 10 * floor($i / 4))." ";
}
?>
```

Without `floor` function:

```
<?php
$input = 20;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $input; $i++) {
    if ($i % 10 == 1 || $i % 10 == 2 || $i % 10 == 4 || $i % 10 == 8)
        echo $i." ";
}
?>
```

But still, have to use additional variable `$i` beside `$input`

Comment: you almost got it bro, but the problem is the range. When the input is 20, it should only display 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18, but it turns out it displays 1 2 4 8 11 12 14 18 21 22 24 28 31 32 34 38 41 42 44 48. There's probably a problem within the range.

Comment: Well, I updated the answer. But it's still use 2 variables `$input` and `$i` though

Comment: Thanks bro, this is by far the most working code that is probably acceptable. Basically that $input will come from post data, so it can be substituted by $_POST['value'] or post('value') with codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$input = 50;
for ($n = 1; $n <= $input; $n += $n % 5) {
    echo "$n ";
}
```

Comment: To me, this solution seems perfect with one loop and variable (Though requires two variables) plus optimized. Vote up!